# Add JWT authorization to AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, health-check

I added health monitoring to my ASPNET.Core web api project using the [AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks) package.
I've also used the [AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI) package to add a simple UI. Everything works just fine up to this step.
Now I want require authorization for the UI so that anyone navigating to the UI URL need to be authenticated before seeing the data.

#### Current code:

I've followed the instructions in the Official GitHub repo and here is my current work so far:

```
// Program.cs file
...
builder.Services
    .AddHealthChecksUI(setupSettings: setup =>
    {
        setup.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("endpoint1", "/healthz");
    })
    .AddPostgreSqlStorage(config.GetConnectionString("SharedDbConnectionString")!);

builder.Services
    .AddHealthChecks()
    .AddCheck<BasicHealthCheck>("basic");

app.MapHealthChecks("healthz", new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthCheckOptions()
    {
        Predicate = _ => true,
        ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
    }).RequireAuthorization(new []{ "OnlyAdmin" });

app.MapHealthChecksUI();
```

#### Current State:

Now the `/healthz` only returns the reports if `Authorization` header is present in the header of request.
When I browse to `/healthz` address the UI is shown however the reports can't be fetched from server due to the 401 status code.

#### Question is

How can I configure the UI to ask for a JWT token and use it in the requests it sends to api?

Comment: I have a test in my side with health check and after adding `app.MapHealthChecks("/healthz").RequireAuthorization();`, it asked me to sign in when I hit `localhost:port/healthz`. I noticed `AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI` is provided by contributor, so I'm afraid we don't have that kind of feature. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPiSf.png